# How to undistort Fisheye sub section

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ffmpeg, computer-vision

How to generate normal views from fisheye view as shown in the image below. [image]

Opencv fisheye model flattens the whole image to birds eye view, but that does not produces the desired result.

One approach could be find equations for 4 edges and build map from transformed view to raw view and use cv::remap function to generate image.

Most of security camera maker provides these transform APIs but how can we do it locally.

image source reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZS-WsKDwxdM

Comment: find a model for your fisheye camera that says what *ray in space* corresponds to each pixel of the fisheye image. usually that means you need to combine the distortion model with the "pinhole" model that the fisheye is mapped to... unless it's a >180 degree camera, then pinhole breaks down. -- then you can synthesize arbitrary perspective views, by calculating the maps required by `cv::remap()` (for each result pixel, figure out what its ray in space is (pinhole camera model), and which fisheye pixel corresponds to that ray in space)

Comment: If you can use something other than OpenCV, then I have two Imagemagick scripts that might be of use, though, they use much simpler camera models and are for nadir/zenith looking fisheye views only. They work only on individual frames. So you would have to loop over each video frame.  See my fisheye2rect and fisheye2pano scripts at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick. In the scripts, you give it a pointing direction and fov for the output rather than some rectangle or "normal view"